# datetime-local input not displaying value?

Tags: php, html, datetime

I am trying to create a simple HTML form and the one element must capture the date and time, I am currently using:

```
 <input type="datetime-local" id="early" name="early" value="02/15/15T03:35">
```

However the issue is that it does not seem to populate the value of the element and just shows the normal blank values?

My format that datetime-local seems to show on Chrome is dd/mm/Y, --:-- (presumably hours:minutes)

Any help is appreciated as to the correct format?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct format shoud be something like this `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM` or `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` where **T** is a string literal **T**
Example

**2016-02-01T03:35** or **2016-02-01T03:35:57**

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="early" name="early" value="2016-02-01T03:35">
```

You can read and check the format [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html#form.data.datetime-local-def)

Comment: if you are using Java for HTML generation, you should apply a pattern for your Date fields `pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"`. [Read more](http://blog.devatlant.com/blog/2018/02/25/how-to-fix-datetime-local-input-in-chrome/)

Comment: Generally speaking, when using Java 8 or higher (or JSP) to produce HTML output, ``java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`` formatter would yield the necessary datetime-local value format.

Answer (score 1):

You should format your value according to [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#page-6) as written here - https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html#form.data.datetime-local

> ```
> The following parts, in exactly the following order:
> A date.
> The literal string "T".
> A time.
> ```

> Example:
> 1985-04-12T23:20:50.52
> 1996-12-19T16:39:57

So try

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="early" name="early" value="2015-02-15T03:35:00">
```